# Upgrading Google Maps javascript v2 to v3 using Business Client IDs

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-maps-api-3

I am using this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3) for Upgrading Google Maps JavaScript Application v2 To v3. Basically my approach is to get the output from api, parse it and load it using MapKit framework, which i am succeeded in doing it using this [code](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions).

My problem : As per the documentation,if we are using google maps for Business customer, we will need to use a Client ID in place of a Key.

so if I use this code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&client=gme-myclientId&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i am getting following output, where all the locations are plotted at single point (probably centre) :

[image: map current output]

if i use this code:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i will get the expected (correct) output as follows:

[image: map expected output without using clientId]

I also ran through this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/guide) for correct use of client id, but dint help.
I am using the same client id that was used for v2, hope that should not create any problem.

Comment: You're right in your assumption, that point off the coast of Ghana is 0,0

Comment: @duncan so what exactly might be the issue?? why i am not getting the expected result by using the correct ClientId, which i used for v2.

Comment: Sorry, no idea, I've never used the client ID attribute.  I can only assume your client ID was only configured for API v2 and that's causing it to not work with v3.  You might just have to get new client IDs

Comment: I highly recommend you reach out to Google Enterprise Support.

Comment: @miguev i feel the problem is not in their side, But still will check.

Comment: I assume you're using your proper client ID, and not "gme-myclientId"? Also, I'm pretty sure client IDs are only linked with URLs, not specific versions of the API.

Comment: @Anthony-GISCOE- sorry for late response. Yes, i cross-checked, i am using the correct ID.

Comment: @Krishanbhag, did you find the issue? Any client id will work equally well with V2 and V3, but in your case it looks like that 0,0 is coming from geocoding or directions (from the JavaScript API) and that might be related to the way you're using MapKit, that's what might need a close look from Google Enterprise Support.

Comment: @miguev hey sorry, forgot to update. i mailed Google enterprise support and they replied me back saying i might be using some of the undocumented variables in my Javascript library. The variable names are automatically generated when the library is minified and can (and often do) change on every release they push. The correct way is to use the documented API methods only. link for using documented API methods : 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the comments to my question, which made me to solve the problem. So, i thought of sharing the solution.

when i am not using the client id,

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the response structure is

```
"overview_path": [{
                    "jb": 37.785610000000005,
                    "kb": -122.41127000000002
                }, … ];
```

But, on using the client id, say gme-myClientId

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&client=gme-myClientId&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the response structure is

```
"overview_path": [{
                    "hb": 37.785610000000005,
                    "ib": -122.41127000000002
                }, …];
```

So, variation in jb,kb to hb,ib was causing the problem, since i was using the variables as key to get the values.

I was using a [third party Code](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions) which internally follows this procedure.

I mailed Google enterprise support and they replied me back saying i might be using some of the undocumented variables in my Javascript library. The variable names are automatically generated when the library is minified and can (and often do) change on every release they push. The correct way is to use the documented API methods only.

link for using documented API methods can be found 
[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

i modified my code to use like the below

```
var latT = someLocationObject.lat();
var longT = someLocationObject.lng();
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Well, to use a client id like "gme-XXXXX" you need to buy a Google Maps for Business licence. Have you already buy one ?

Regards,

Comment: As miguel says, i think you have to open a request on the Google support portal.
Also can you give us an access to the web page where you face the issue to see what's wrong ?

Comment: Actually, in my reply to miguev's comment (hey sorry, forgot to...) i have clearly told about the request in their support portal and their reply. i dint try it still. once i will start working on it. i will update the status along with the web page access.

Comment: think, i have not clearly explained the problem, let me brief, I will query direction api of google, parse it and load it using MapKit framework to iPad, which on using without client id is working perfectly but, on use of it is showing the location to (0,0). i suspect there could be two problem for it one problem with client id or else some key value for client and normal response is different.